# My functions don't follow the synchronous using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I don't know why the `handleSum` function doesn't sum the updated value came from `handleInput` when I invoke the function `handleAll` through the `onChange` input event. It seems that sums with the previous value. Can you bring some light here? Thank you!

Here the JS part:

```
const card = () => {

//hook defined
const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
    p1h1: "",
    p1h2: "",
});
const [result, setResult] = React.useState("")

//handle input change  
const handleInput = function(e){
    setInput({
        ...input, 
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};

//handle sum
const handleSum = function(){
    const { p1h1, p1h2 } = input;            
    setResult(Number(p1h1) + Number(p1h2));
}

   //handle result player
   const handleAll = function (e) {
        handleInput(e)
        setTimeout (()=> {handleSum()},1000) // I inserted this setTimeout to double sure that this is executing after the previous function but didn't work.
    }
}
```

Here the HTML part:

```
<input 
  name= "p1h1" 
  value={input.p1h1} 
  onChange={handleAll} 
  type= "number" 
  min="0" 
</input>

<input 
  name= "p1h2" 
  value={input.p1h2} 
  onChange={handleAll} 
  type= "number" 
  min="0" 
</input>

<h2>Result sum: {result}</h2>
```

Comment: From what I can tell you're not using the `useState` hook from within a functional component, but instead with a function `card`. [That's not how you should be using hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: If that actually runs in a functional component, then your `handleAll` function uses the previous state of `input` variable. Because once you call `handleInput`, and subsequently `setInput`, you create a new state object. But `handleAll` uses a state object from the previous render phase(thanks to closures) - that's why it's lagging behind.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rules of Hooks (see my comment) you may not use hooks except *at the toplevel of functional components*. Not nested in other functions, not in `if` not in `for`, etc.

So you need to make a functional component, like `const Test = () => { return (<div />); }`

Then you need to call your hook, and render your HTML as JSX from within that component. You can then use your `handleInput` function to update the state.

*You do not need another state to hold the result of the addition*. It's OK to just compute that during render.

This will work:

```
const Test = () => {
  //hook defined
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
    p1h1: '',
    p1h2: '',
  });

  //handle input change
  const handleInput = function (e) {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const { p1h1, p1h2 } = input;
  const result = Number(p1h1) + Number(p1h2);

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="p1h1" value={input.p1h1} onChange={handleInput} type="number" min="0"></input>

      <input name="p1h2" value={input.p1h2} onChange={handleInput} type="number" min="0"></input>

      <h2>Result sum: {result}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleksandar! That worked out! Super clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling `handleSum` is not right. You should use a `useEffect` hook to re-render the element when a particular state changes as an array of dependencies (2nd argument of `useEffect`). You can learn more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

```
const App = () => { 

const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
    p1h1: "",
    p1h2: "",
});
React.useEffect(() => {
    handleSum()
  }, [input])

const [result, setResult] = React.useState("")

//handle input change  
const handleInput = function(e){
    setInput({
        ...input, 
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};

//handle sum
const handleSum = function(){
    const { p1h1, p1h2 } = input;            
    setResult(Number(p1h1) + Number(p1h2));
}
  return (
    <div>

      <input
        name= "p1h1" 
        value={input.p1h1} 
        onChange={handleInput} 
        type= "number" 
        min="0">
      </input>

      <input 
        name= "p1h2" 
        value={input.p1h2} 
        onChange={handleInput} 
        type= "number" 
        min="0">
      </input>
    <h2>Result sum: {result}</h2>
</div>
```

)
}

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked out! There was a warning saying "React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleSum'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" but I solved by including the handleSum function inside the useEffect:     
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleSum = function(){
            const { p1h1, p1h2 } = input;            
            setResult(Number(p1h1) + Number(p1h2));
        }
        handleSum()},[input]) Thanks a lot! :)